# Simple "Sub Sub" Option

Tags: html, css

I've created a simple navigation with 2 levels of sub menus. I'm looking for the 'sub sub' option to show up to the right of its parent and not below. I'd appreciate any assistance with the CSS. The html and css are below along with JS fiddle link as well.

Thank you everyone in advance,

HTML

```
<body>
<header>
    <h1><a href="http://www.test.com/demo">Test Website</a></h1>
    Just another WordPress site <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://www.test.com/demo/" >
    <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
    </div>
    </form>    <div class="nav-bar">
     <nav class="main-nav"><ul id="menu-main-nav" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-238" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-236 current_page_item menu-item-238"><a href="http://www.test.com/demo/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-241" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-241"><a href="http://www.test.com/demo/second-page/">Second Page</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-243" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-243"><a href="http://www.test.com/demo/sub-option-page-1/">Sub Option Page 1</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-245" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-245"><a href="http://www.test.com/demo/sub-option-page-2/">Sub Option Page 2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-247" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-247"><a href="http://www.test.com/demo/sub-sub-option-1/">Sub Sub Option 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></nav>    </div>
</header>
</body>
```

CSS

```
ul, li{ margin:0; padding:0; border:0; outline:0; font-size:100%; vertical-align:baseline; background:transparent; } 

.nav-bar {
    background: #008752;
    height: 50px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #333;   
}

.main-nav ul, .main-nav li{
    display: inline
}

.main-nav a {
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
}

.main-nav a:hover {
    background:#00FFFB;
    color: black;   
}


.main-nav ul li {
    position: relative; 
    float: left;
}

.main-nav ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: -99999px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0; 
    background: #037A5A;
    text-align: left;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #BFBFBF;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;

}

.main-nav ul ul a {
    width: 135px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    display:block;  
}

.main-nav ul li:hover > ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.main-nav ul ul ul {
    background:#830002; 
    text-align: left;
}

.main-nav ul ul ul a {
    width: 135px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: block; 
}

.main-nav ul ul ul a:hover {
    background:#1041A3;
    color: white;
}   

.main-nav ul ul li:hover > ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 170px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y24p5/1/

Comment: Hey PSL, thanks for the response and yes, the end result is just like I wanted it. I should have mentioned this in my initial question, but I was hoping for a solution that didn't involve manually adding classes to "sub sub" options since these menus were being dynamically generated in WP. The solution presented by DavidPaulJunior works ideally since no additional classes are needed. Thank you nonetheless :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to tweak a couple of styles on the `.main-nav ul ul li:hover > ul`.

```
.main-nav ul ul li:hover > ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
```

This will set it to 100% left of it's parent, and inline with the top of it's parent.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Y24p5/10/)**

Comment: The quality and speed of the support on this forum never ceases to amaze. This is the perfect solution. Thanks DavidPaulJunior!